# Laravel query on which is more performant

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am fairly new to laravel and sql I noticed that a lot of things can be achieved using different techniques. I want to know which is more performant?

```
Message::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get()
```

or

```
auth()->user()->messages
```

Someone I know warned me about eager loading that it greatly affects performance.

Comment: It's not entirely an issue but preemptive solution to a possible problem that I might face in the future. I'm creating a messaging app so I expected that my messages table will contain millions of data. I'm concious of the performance of all my queries

Comment: There are other ways to write those queries too if you really wanted to. Worry about performance issues if/when you encounter them. Until then use whatever technique(s) make sense that result in achiving your goal (of solving problems). I'm not sure why someone would `'warn'` you about eager loading as it solves the `n+1` query problem when accessing relations and so is a good thing, unless you eager load and never access the relation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that both examples shown will produce the same `messages` query.

Answer (score 0):

The two methods provided, should perform similar database queries in the background. One to fetch the user and another one to fetch all the messages for that single user. Not much difference.

---

It can become a problem when you start fetching things inside a loop. For example:

```php
$users = User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    // Messages are fetched separately for every single user inside this loop 
    // since the relationship is not present. 
    // Query like: SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = ?
    \Log::info($user->messsages); 
}
```

We can solve this by eager loading all the messages by doing:

```php
User::with('messages')->all();
```

This way only a single query will be executed like `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)` and these messages will be mapped to correct users on the PHP side. So when you run your foreach loop, the relationship is already loaded and no additional queries are executed.

---

On the web you can find more information about it by searching for "Laravel n+1 problem". Name comes from the reason that without eager loading in this scenario you execute an additional (+1) query for every single model. With eager loading this can be solved with just 2 queries.

[Laracasts episode: Eager loading](https://laracasts.com/lessons/eager-loading)